# Python3.6: pip is installed but not working in windows

Tags: python, pip

I have installed python 3.6.5 followed by pip using following command:
python get-pip.py

Added path till Scripts folder to "User PATH variable" as I dont have admin rights.

But When I am trying to access pip (pip --version), it throws me errors which mainly relate to not finding the module. Description is given below.

```
File "....\Python\python-3.6.5-embed-amd64\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Comment: *python 3.6.0 … python-3.6.5-embed-amd64* two different pythons in PATH?

Comment: Sorry, I am using python-3.6.5.